# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Tags: jquery, file-upload

Hi i'm trying to use Jquery File Upload. I've got it work on FireFox and Chrome properly. As usual, IE has to stand out and throw tantrums to make our lives more interesting. I'm getting this error when i hit the upload button. Has anyone encountered this error and any suggestions as to why its happening?

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'find' 
jquery.ui.widget.js, line 479 character 3

I'm having issues in IE9. I think same issue is in IE7 and IE8 as well.

Here is the piece of code.

Instead of Jquery Templates i'm using JSRender here but it shouldn't make a lot of difference as i'm using my own callbacks.

```
var oXHR = {};
var iUpload =1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;

    'use strict';


    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        dataType: 'json',
        url: filepath,
        formData: data,
        dropZone: $('#dropcontainer'),
        fileInput: $('input:file'),
        add: function(e, data) {

            $('#fileslist').prepend($.render([{ ID: 'upload'+iUpload, NAME: data.files[0].name, SIZE: data.files[0].size }], 'fileUploadTemplate'));

            data.context = 'upload'+iUpload;
            oXHR['upload'+iUpload] = data;

            iUpload++;
        },
        progress: function(e, data) {

            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)/100;
            $('#filespending'+data.context).css('backgroundPosition',-350+(350*progress));

        },
        done: function(e, data) {
            var filedata = jQuery.parseJSON(data.jqXHR.responseText);

            console.log(filedata)
            if(filedata.STATUS){
                $('#filespending'+data.context).remove();

                $('#fileslist').prepend($.render([{ FILEID: filedata.VALUE.FILEID, NAME: filedata.VALUE.NAME, SIZE: filedata.VALUE.FILESIZE,DATEMODIFIED:filedata.VALUE.DATEMODIFIED }], 'fileListTemplate'));

            }
            else{
                $('#filespending'+data.context).addClass('erroruploadingfile');

            }



        },
        start: function(e){
            console.log('start')
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
        }

    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

    $('#fileupload').unbind();
    $('#fileupload').click(function(){
        var i = 1;
        $.each(oXHR, function(key, value) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(oXHR[key]))
            oXHR[key] = oXHR[key].submit();

            i++;
            if(i == iUpload) {
                iUpload = 1;
                oXHR = {};
            }

        });

    });

    // Show feedback on dragover
    $(document).bind('dragover', function(e) {
        var dropZone = $('#dropcontainer'),
            timeout = window.dropZoneTimeout;
        if(timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        if(e.target === dropZone[0]) {
            dropZone.addClass('containerdroppable');
        } else {
            dropZone.removeClass('containerdroppable');
        }
        window.dropZoneTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            window.dropZoneTimeout = null;
            dropZone.removeClass('containerdroppable');
        }, 100);
    });

    $(document).bind('drop dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

I'm also using the jQuery UI Widget 1.9.1+amd

Comment: Which version of IE? Can you post a small, complete code example that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Which version of jquery.ui.widget.js?

Comment: (To answer the questions asked in the comments, use the "`edit`" link at the bottom of your question and edit your question with new information.)

Comment: I'm using the jQuery UI Widget 1.9.1+amd

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fine a better plugin that works well with IE7+ browsers and Mac browsers as well.

http://fineuploader.com/

Easy to implement and works without JQuery.